# Correct ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im trying to make a dual axis plot using the following data table (I exported the exact table into Excel to examine the data). The data in the table runs until '2022-02-07' and for each date there is corresponding data for the other variables. Using the code below, I get the following error:

**CODE:**

```
SZ_Cobmined_Plot = SZ_Cobmined[['Day','Total','%_ESI_3','%_ESI_4','%_ESI_5']]
SZ_Cobmined_Plot = SZ_Cobmined_Plot.fillna(0)

g7.bar(SZ_Cobmined_Plot['Day'],SZ_Cobmined_Plot['Total'], color='slategray', label = 'Total')
g7.set_ylabel('Total Volume')
g7=g7.twinx()
g7.plot(g7.get_xticks(), SZ_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_3'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('green'))
g7.plot(g7.get_xticks(), SZ_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_4'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('dodgerblue'))
g7.plot(g7.get_xticks(), SZ_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_5'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('purple'))
g7.set_ylabel('% LWBS By Acuity')
g7.set_title('SZ LWBS Acuity % By Volume')
g7.legend(["%_ESI_3", "%_ESI_4","%_ESI_5"])
g7.tick_params(labelrotation=90)
```

**ERROR:**

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (135,)
```

**TABLE:**

[image]

.....

[image]

Comment: Did you try using `SZ_Cobmined_Plot['Day']` instead of `g7.get_xticks()`?  Also note that giving the same variable name to both the original and the `twinx` ax isn't recommended, as it leads to confusion.

Comment: switching 'SZ_Cobmined_Plot['Day']' for 'g7.get_xticks()' creates a different error 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'SZ_Cobmined_Plot'. Also not sure what you mean by last sentence, both variables on 1st and 2nd Y axis share the same X axis variable, which is 'Day'

Comment: What's the problem with `g7.plot(SZ_Cobmined_Plot['Day'], SZ_Cobmined_Plot['%_ESI_3'].values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0, color=('green'))`?  The idea is to nowhere use `g7.get_xticks()`, but instead the exact day-values that go together with the column you're plotting.  And please don't use `g7=g7.twinx()`, but please give the 2nd y axis another name.